# How Trash Check point interval works in hadoop? and why checkpoint_intereval is required?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop2, hadoop-streaming

I have tried this practically to understand the concept but I am still not clear.

say for example 
**fs.trash.interval=9min and 
fs.trash.checkpoint.interval=2min**

Now I delete file1 at 10:00 and file2 at 10:03.
It says it is moved to " /user/xxx/.trash/current" and that current directory  is disappeared within some time and I can see checkpoint folder
there and it looks like this " /user/xxx/.trash/(date_somenumber)".

As per my understanding file1 should be permanently deleted at 10:09 and file2 at 10:11.

If checkpoint happens every 2min say
1st  at 10:02
2nd     10:04
3rd     10:06
4th     10:08
5th     10:10
6th     10:12
so file1 should get deleted in 5th checkpoint_intereval and file2 in 6th interval.

my doubt is

1) **when does current directory disappears? during checkpoint_intereval or any time early?**

(for me it looks like it is disappearing within a min)

2) **for every checkpoint interval new folder is formed only if new file is deleted and is rest abstract ?**

(so, does it mean every 2min checkpointing is abstract for us and it is not changing the directory name every 2min)

3) **we had set trash interval to 9min (for example) with intention of having the file for 9min in trash so why do we need checkpoint_interval to check every 2min (for example) when we know it will get automatically deleted after 9min.**

(is checkpoint  a process to delete files ?? because when we say checkpoint_intereval=0 still by default it takes trash interval= 9min as value and checkpoint occurs at every 9min)

please correct my understanding if I am wrong by clarifying these doubts.

Answer (score 1):

`/user/username/.Trash/Current/` is used to hold the recently deleted HDFS files.

`/user/username/.Trash/CheckpointTime/` is created during the checkpoint interval which is actually a renamed `current` directory. There can be multiple checkpoints depending on the time difference that exists between `trash.interval` and `checkpoint.interval`.

> **fs.trash.interval** : Number of minutes after which the checkpoint gets deleted. 
>   **fs.trash.checkpoint.interval** : Number of minutes between trash
>   checkpoints.

**1)** The Current directory is renamed with the timestamp as the Checkpoint directory during the checkpoint interval and not anytime earlier.

**2)** Only if there are any `current` or recent deletions within the interval.

A snippet from [Trash](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/TrashPolicyDefault.java) class used by Hadoop:

```
  private void createCheckpoint(Path trashRoot, Date date) throws IOException {
    if (!fs.exists(new Path(trashRoot, CURRENT))) {
      return;
    }
    .....
    Path checkpoint = checkpointBase;
    Path current = new Path(trashRoot, CURRENT);
    ......
    while (true) {
      try {
        fs.rename(current, checkpoint, Rename.NONE);
        .....
      .....
```

**3)** It is the checkpointer process that checks every 2 minutes does the deletion as well. Every 2 minutes as configured, the checkpointer process will move the files in the `current` directory to a new checkpoint directory and deletes all the checkpoints created earlier which are older than the `fs.trash.interval`.

Quoting from the official [documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsDesign.html#Space_Reclamation):

> Most recent deleted files are moved to the current trash directory
>   (/user/username/.Trash/Current), and in a configurable interval,
>   HDFS creates checkpoints (under /user/username/.Trash/date) for
>   files in current trash directory and deletes old checkpoints when they are expired.